# Alert box not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, confirm

I have my .js file in a seperate folder to the index.html

Here is the contents of buildit.js

```
//On change event for the textbox plate text
      function setValue(target){
        var platetext = target.value;
        $('#numberplateyellow').empty();
        $('#numberplatewhite').empty();


        var plateregex=/^[A-Za-z]{2}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[ ]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]{3}$/ 
        if (document.platebuilder.target.value.search(plateregex)==-1){
        var answer = confirm ("Non LEGAL Plate Detected (YES WE WILL SHOW THE AGREE BOX ONCE I HAVE IT FROM TOM) \n\n Do you understand that this is now classed as a show plate ?");
        if (answer) {
        $('#numberplateyellow').append(platetext);
        $('#numberplatewhite').append(platetext);
        }
      }
      }
```

These are called on the onchange in a input box, could you explain why the alert box is not showing and also if you get a chance is it possible to .append after each letter typed ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Did you try `window.confirm`?

Comment: `alert` isn't going to show when you use `confirm`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this file is getting included in the first place?

Comment: YES 100000000000000000000000000000% sure as it did append (before the if statement about answer was there)

Comment: yes sorry i meant confirm, it was a alert then i thought a confirm was more appropriate and please not it didn't work with the alert box

Comment: Can you give an example of the string you are trying to match with that regex?

Comment: what does `alert(document.platebuilder.target.value.search(plateregex)==-1)` placed above `if` say?

Comment: also, is the `[ ]` valid regexp? Shouldn't that be just `\s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are passing an  into the function you want to reference it without the "document.platebuilder"

I am not really clear on what you want to see when someone is changing the content of the input field??

```
function setValue(target)
{
    var platetext = target.value;
    $('#numberplateyellow').empty();
    $('#numberplatewhite').empty();

    var plateregex=/^[A-Za-z]{2}[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[ ]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]{3}$/
    if (target.value.search(plateregex)==-1)
    {
        var answer = "Non LEGAL Plate Detected (YES WE WILL SHOW THE AGREE BOX ONCE I HAVE IT FROM TOM) \n\n Do you understand that this is now classed as a show plate ?";
        alert(answer);
        $('#numberplateyellow').append(platetext);
        $('#numberplatewhite').append(platetext);
    }
}
```

If you want to run this for every key pressed then you need to set this to run on the keypressed event rather than onchange (however this would get quite annoying because of the alert...)